# \ref is automatically prefixing the string "Fig." to figure numbers and "Table" to table numbers. Why?

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir, chemstyle

I'm not sure what package I've loaded, but my figures are being printed automatically as "Fig. #", while my tables are printed automatically as "Table #".

Is there a way to just get the number?

Also, I've read the default is for Figures to be labeled as "Figure" not "Fig.", I am not sure what I've loaded. How can I decipher the source (or return the behavior to the original).

My preamble is quite complicated, I'm not sure I could simply comment out various packages and see which one removes the behavior I'm wanting to change.

--EDIT--

As requested here is a MWE. I have commented out the other packages that I am including in my main document, just in case it changes your answer or assistance.

```
\documentclass[oneside,openany,openbib,11pt]{memoir}
%\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, headsep=0.1in, head=0.4in, includehead, includefoot, marginparsep=0in, marginparwidth=0in,footskip=0.4in]{geometry}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}
%\usepackage{bpchem} %labeling and referencing of compounds
\usepackage[journal=rsc,tracking=bpchem]{chemstyle} %for schemes and such
%\usepackage{textcomp} %use for symbols
%\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
%\usepackage{multirow} % for mutlirow
%\usepackage{mciteplus} % for multicitations
%\usepackage[super=true,journal=jacsat,maxauthors=0]{achemso} %for proper citation formatting
%\usepackage{flafter} %floats appear after their
%\usepackage{floatrow} %float customization
%\usepackage{textgreek} %greek text
%\usepackage{bm} %bold math text
%\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage{glossaries}
%\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0},plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels=\thepage,bookmarks=true,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{testing}\label{test}
\includegraphics{test}
\end{figure}

\ref{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The default with standard LaTeX classes is just the number. So, you are using a class, package or code which changes that or which uses a different default. If you cannot say what that thing is, given access to the code which is responsible, it beats me how you expect other people to know. Of course, somebody might try guessing and you might get lucky. Or you might not. Why can't you comment things out to see what's responsible? If you are loading things-you-know-not-what-they-do, pruning is definitely required regardless.

Comment: I could certainly post my entire preamble, or a list of the packages being used (would that be helpful?). I used the same preamble for my master's thesis, which was written a few years ago. However, the behavior needs to change for just this one piece. But the other 90% of the structure and form is useful for my current thesis, so going back to this document seemed like a reasonable choice rather than reinvent it all from scratch.

Comment: No. That's why you create a *minimal* working example which reproduces the behaviour. We neither need nor want your entire preamble. Although it does sound as if you should probably do some pruning - but that's not relevant here.

Comment: By creating a MWE, I will likely figure it out, as that will narrow the list of packages. I was hoping to avoid such an time-intensive process. But alright.

Comment: Yes. That's how creating an MWE often goes. Do you really have so little idea what your preamble does that you can't make a reasonable guess that quite a lot of it is irrelevant? As I say, I get the very strong impression that you have a preamble which has accumulated a lot of excess baggage. If so, pruning it is well worth your time. Such preambles make it enormously difficult to understand, maintain and diagnose your code. Every problem will take longer to solve than it should, if you manage to solve it at all.

Comment: It is not clear if the undesired "Fig." appear  in  the caption lables or in text references  If the second, are you using the `cleveref` package and `\cref` (not `\ref`) for cross-references? May be `\vref` also with `varioref` package? Or some other listed [here](https://www.ctan.org/topic/label-ref) ?

Comment: Turns out my chemstyle package loads varioref by default

Comment: I have updated my answer to include an MWE @cfr

Comment: Thanks! Off-topic: you shouldn't need to declare those graphics extensions: they (and others) are all supported out-of-the-box. (Unless you have a really ancient TeX installation.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to reset the macro `\figurename`. Its default value, if the `chemstyle` package is loaded, is "`Fig.`".

You should add

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\figurename{Figure}}
```

to the preamble to change the macro to, you guessed it, "`Figure`".

Second, you need to provide the option `varioref=false` when loading the `chemstyle` package:

```
\usepackage[journal=rsc,tracking=bpchem,varioref=false]{chemstyle}
```

This will suppress the prefixing of `Fig.` (or `Figure`) in the cross-reference.

Remember to recompile twice to fully propagate all changes.

Comment: That took care of the first part (changing the "Fig" to "Figure". But \ref still prints "Figure 0.1" automatically and not just "0.1" as the default is. How do I achieve that (I believe that is an impact of the chemstyle package). Which seems to load a bunch of other packages too.

Comment: @JM - I've edited my answer to show how to get rid of the "Fig." (or "Figure" prefix in the cross-reference callouts.

Comment: Thank you, are there any unintended consequences in my document that might arise from disabling varioref? I also saw that maybe I could change labelformat{figure}{#1} would this also work?

Comment: @JM - How do you create cross-references in general? Do you use `\ref`, `\autoref`, `\vref`, or some other mechanism?

Comment: Just \ref, I append my own tags such as "Figure" "Table" etc, through custom commands so I have more control (made commands like "figref" "tabref", etc...

Comment: @JM - I'd say, compile a real document or two with the new settings and check for unwanted outcomes.

Comment: @JM - If you're committed to keep using the `memoir` document class, you may also want to look into using `\fref`, `\tref`, etc to cross-reference figures, tables, and so on.